# Play Facebook game without asking for credentials

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms

Is there a way to run a Facebook game directly from C# windows forms application without asking the user for his Facebook credentials (like hosting the game and as the user to allow access)?

What i want to achieve is creating a windows forms application from which players can play multiple Facebook games and share there score in a network and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know Facebook games are hosted on the developers server and Facebook embeds them. You could try to find the game itself, but I don't think that you will be able to bypass any integrated login. How would fetch the score? Extracting it from the local running instance and pushing it to your server would make it manipulateable.

However, if you get access to the games, I would recommend that you build a wrapper for the games and host them yourself and then embed them via a Webview/Webcontrol etc.

Comment: I first thought about using WebControl to host the game but that will end up requesting the user for his facebook credetnials. So is there any way to get around this ?

Comment: As I said: No, not aslong as you don't have the source or a version without login. This games are made for facebook and will mostly not work without.